# extension of class to compare two objects

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following class on Java:

```
public class Entity<T extends Comparable<T>> { 
  private T t; 
  private int id; 
  private Entity<T> innerEntity; 

  public Entity(T t) {
    this(t, 100, null); 
  } 

  public Entity(T t, int id) {
    this(t,id, null); 
  }

  public Entity(T t, int id, Entity<T> innerEntity) {
    this.t = t; 
    this.id = id; 
    this.innerEntity = innerEntity; 
  } 

  public T getT() {
    return t; 
  }

  public void setT(T t) {
    this.t = t; 
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id; 
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  } 

  public Entity<T> getInnerEntity() {
    return innerEntity;
  } 

  public void setInnerEntity(Entity<T> innerEntity) {
    this.innerEntity = innerEntity; 
  } 

  @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) 
      return true; 
    if (!(o instanceof Entity)) 
      return false; 

    Entity<?> entity = (Entity<?>) o; 

    if (id != entity.id) 
      return false; 
    if (!t.equals(entity.t)) 
      return false; 
    return innerEntity.equals(entity.innerEntity); 

  }

  @Override public int hashCode() {
    int result = t.hashCode(); 

    result = 31 * result + id; 
    result = 31 * result + innerEntity.hashCode(); 
    return result; 
  }  
}
```

How can we extend this  class, so that a list of objects of its type can be moved to the Collections.sort () method, **without a comparator**, and any two objects can be compared in the following order:

1. By the T parameter value.
2. By id (int type) .
3. By  Entity.

?

Comment: What do you mean by "*can be compared... By the T parameter value*"?

Comment: You need to add `implements Comparable<Entity<T>>` and then implement the `compareTo(Entity<T>)` method that the interface requires.

Comment: @StephenC but should I implement Comparable<Entity> with entity class?

Comment: If I implement Comparable<Entity<T>> with EntityComp that is not correct

types should be equal

Answer (score 1):

From a typing perspective, you need to add

```
 implements Comparable<Entity<T>>
```

to the class declaration, and then implement the compareTo(Entity) method that the interface requires.

In comments you queried this saying:

> Should I implement `Comparable<Entity>` with entity class?  If I implement `Comparable<Entity<T>>` with EntityComp that is not correct types should be equal.

I think you are saying that you should be able to compare `Entity` instances with different type parameters.

First of all, it is not clear (to me) what this class *actually stands for*.  It is not apparent from the code itself.  (Perhaps javadoc comments would help?)

The problem with your idea is that `implement Comparable<Entity>` will give you compilation warnings ... about raw types.

And `implement Comparable<Entity<?>>` probably won't work either from the typing perspective.  You have declared `T extends Comparable<T>`, so if your `compareTo` method attempts to compare a `T` against any other type (including `?`), you should get a compilation error.

I suspect that there is something conceptually wrong with your modelling:

- Maybe you are trying to use static (generic) typing in a case where more dynamic typing is called for?
- Maybe, `Entity<Type1>` and `Entity<Type2>` *shouldn't* be comparable.
- Maybe the issue is this: *"... a list of objects of its type sorted with `Collections.sort()` ..."* and the notion that you put (say) `Entity<Type1>` and `Entity<Type2>` instances into the same collection.